# Can Shadow Word: Death kill a Spellbender minion?

Tags: hearthstone

Suppose my opponent has a Spellbender secret and a minion with at least 5 attack.  I cast Shadow Word: Death on the big minion.  Spellbender is supposed to summon a 1/3 minion as the new target, but Shadow Word: Death can only target a minion with 5 or more attack.

Does the new minion get destroyed, does the spell fail, or does something else entirely happen?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The secret will trigger and the 1/3 will die.

Generally any spell cast on a minion will trigger the secret and affect the 1/3 regardless of whether or not the 1/3 could usually be targeted by that spell. So things like execute (which normally only affects damaged minions) or bestial wrath (which normally only affects beasts) would also affect the 1/3.

Comment: That makes sense, intuitively. The limitations on Shadow Words / Execute / etc. are *targeting* restrictions. The effect is the same (kill the target), so if a Spellbinder grabs it, the targeting restriction is sidestepped, and they die.